# How do you read POST data in an ASP.Net MVC 3 Web API 2.1 controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, http-post, asp.net-web-api2

This does not seem to be as easy as I thought. I found some solutions on the web, but they are not working for me. I have an ASP.Net MVC 3 project with the Microsoft ASP.Net Web API 2.1 nuget package installed. Now, I want to be able to read data posted to a web api controller. The data sent will vary, so I cannot used a strongly typed ViewModel.

Here are the solutions I tried:

```
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        ...
    }


    public void Post([FromBody]List<string> values)
    {
        ...
    }


    public void Post([FromBody]NameValueCollection values)
    {
        ...
    }
```

But my value or values variables are always empty. I know the controller is receiving data however because I can check it by accessing (System.Web.HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"].Request.Form. It does not look like the proper way to retrieve the data though. There ought to be a cleaner way.

**UPDATE:**

Here is how I am posting the information:

I am posting the data from another controller in the same web application:

```
    public ActionResult SendEmailUsingService()
    {
        dynamic email = new ExpandoObject();

        email.ViewName = "EmailTest";
        email.From = "fromaddress@yahoo.com";
        email.To = "toaddress@gmail.com";
        email.Fullname = "John Smith";
        email.Url = "www.mysite.com";

        IDictionary<string, object> data = email;

        using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            string url = BaseUrlNoTrailingSlash + Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "Emailer" });
             var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data.ToNameValueCollection());
        }

        return View();
    }
```

And here is what I am getting in my Post web api controller if I declare an httpContext variable like this:

```
var httpContext = (System.Web.HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
```

> httpContext.Request.Form =
>   {ViewName=EmailTest&From=fromaddress%40yahoo.com&To=toaddress%40gmail.com&Fullname=John+Smith&Url=www.mysite.com}

httpContext.Request.Form is a System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection {System.Web.HttpValueCollection}

Comment: Can you add examples of how you are Posting the data to the API?

Comment: @JonSusiak Please see the UPDATE section in my original post. I just added the information you are asking me.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the answer to my question here:

[Web API Form Data Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605358/web-api-form-data-collection)

The solution is to use FormDataCollection:

```
    public void Post([FromBody]FormDataCollection formData)
    {
        ...
    }
```