# Slack Interactive Buttons / Form URL Encoded / webapi / response

Tags: asp.net-web-api, slack-api, slack

With Slack's interactive buttons, when a user clicks a button, they create an outgoing web hook to the specified web server.

We are receiving that webhook via ASP.NET, and learned the very hard way about [FormDataCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605358/web-api-form-data-collection).

When a request is received using this format (CONTENT-TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded), how does one reply to the request?  [Slack documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons#how_to_respond_to_message_button_actions) isn't helping me much. I know its in JSON, but how to put that JSON back into a FORMDataCollection?  We are attempting to user the CreateReponse extension method off the original request.